# jQuery off().remove() or .remove().off() performance

Tags: javascript, jquery

I read different answers on stackoverflow on how can I destroy a wigdet/jQueryObject and unbind all events on it.

And here is what I came up with.

1. `$('selector').remove().off().find("*").off();`
2. `$('selector').off().remove().find("*").off();`

**Question:**
My question is regarding the performance of above 2.
Will there be a performance difference by changing the order.
Is there a difference between using `off()` after `remove()` or before `remove()`?
Or is it the same and the order is not important, performance wise?

**Update :**

also what about Empty

1. `$('selector').empty().off().find("*").off();`
2. `$('selector').off().empty().find("*").off();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to do that at all, the documentation for [**remove()**](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) states

> In addition to the elements themselves, **all bound events** and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.

so all you need is

```
$('selector').remove();
```

Comment: and what about empty() ? Actually I am using .empty() becasue i dont want parent div to to be removed so ```$('selector').empty().off().find("*").off();```. What now ?

Comment: @django - Read the documentation, it states "To avoid memory leaks, jQuery removes other constructs such as data and event handlers from the child elements before removing the elements themselves."